# Best way to store multiple user attribute collection

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Question about best db design practices for the following scenario:

I have a user table which stores information like password, the department user belongs to, Email e.t.c. I also have to create another table to store user access information. I have users with access as following:

1. userid 123 : [line of business: abc, xyz,e.t.c.], [Role: Team leader, Regular User e.t.c.], [Company: 1234, 54666, e.t.c.]
2. userid 345: [line of business: abc, xyz,  987,  e.t.c.], [Role: Team leader, Maintenance e.t.c.], [Company: 1234, 54666, e.t.c.]

Basically, a user can have any combinations of different access for each of these categories.

The way i was thinking is in this table, create 3 columns for each type of access and store each category in the form of xml, otherwise i have to create 3 different tables for each categories, t_user_Lob, t_user_role, t_user_company.

what is the best way to do this?

I also thought about storing them as csv values in each column but i heard that it's goes against the relational normalization rules.

I also like json way to storing data but i am using sql server 2012 and it's hell to parse/compare values in json columns in 2012.

Thanks

Comment: 2012 has support for json. In SQL server traditional way would be to use different tables like businesses, roles, companies. There are other databases if you like that you could do those with say arrays.

Comment: cetin, there is no json support in 2012. can you tell me what you are talking about

Comment: My bad, 2016. That explains why I like the RDBMS that have it much before since 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store them in three separate tables.

Your question isn't clear about what relationships are needed, but basically you use three tables to create a many-to-many relationship.

```
Entity A
Entity B
Relationship (A - B)
```

Comment: The relationship is many to many. one user can have many attribute values (like 1 or more roles, or 1 or more Company) . 1 attribute value can belong multiple users.

Comment: Yes, exactly.   Is there some reason you think my answer doesn't address that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the combinatorics aren't outlandish, I would create a table, call it user_access, with every combination of role and company and give each row a unique value.  Then create a third table, call it user_access_people with a user ID and an associated user_access value.  So user_access_people would have your many to many relationship between user_id and user_access_Id. It would have multiple rows per each user_ID when necessary.

You can then join these tables to check for whatever value from the user_access columns that you are looking for.